# can't connect to the database server from the client

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating a window application with a SQL server database. The application need to be installed on a terminal server and other client machine should works with this application. 
I have installed this application and SQL Server Express 2008 on server and application worked currently on server but not on client. I got an error on client machine through my application over connecting to the database on server. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a firewall is blocking it. It could be many things that cause this.

Comment: Probably a permissions issue.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Please provide the exact error message and any screenshots.  There is a good chance that the firewall is blocking your communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default installation of SQL Server Express is to allow only local connection.

See this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165718(v=sql.105).aspx